# Python authentication does not work on HTTPS page

Tags: python, authentication, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am quite new to `Python` but I receive some error message to log into this page.

I am thinking it may have something to do with `Javascript` being used but I am not sure. Any ideas?

I also tried with `BeautifulSoup` but it seems that the data sent is not attributed to the Form for authentication.

Below is the code which i tried with.

```
import requests 

url = "virtelaview.net/web/guest/home" 
myobj = {'login': 'MYLOGIN', 'password': 'MYPASS'} 
x = requests.post(url, data = myobj, auth = ('login', 'password'), verify=False)
```

Comment: '''
import requests

url = "http://www.virtelaview.net/web/guest/home"
myobj = {'login': 'MYLOGIN', 'password': 'MYPASS'}
x = requests.post(url, data = myobj, auth = ('login', 'password'), verify=False)
'''

Comment: but which is the error? ...and what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are passing the wrong login `url` and the important point which you skipped is to maintain the session with fetching the `Session id` firstly and then passing it to the `headers`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

headers = {
    'COOKIE_SUPPORT': 'true',
    'GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID': 'en_US',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'
}
data = {
    '_58_redirect': '',
    'login': 'a@a.com',
    'password': 'testpass'
}
url = 'https://www.virtelaview.net/web/guest/home?p_auth=&p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&saveLastPath=0&_58_struts_action=/login/login'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    bo = dict(s.cookies)
    headers['JSESSIONID'] = bo['JSESSIONID']
    r = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Because i used wrong login details so i got the following response:

```
<div class="portlet-msg-error">Authentication failed. Please try again.</div>
```

That's confirm I'm on the right track.

Another solution if the above code did not logged you. here i fetched the `p_auth` parameter `value` during each request because it's dynamic.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

headers = {
    'COOKIE_SUPPORT': 'true',
    'GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID': 'en_US',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'
}
data = {
    '_58_redirect': '',
    'login': 'a@a.com',
    'password': 'testpass'
}
url = 'https://www.virtelaview.net/web/guest/home?p_auth=&p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&saveLastPath=0&_58_struts_action=/login/login'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    bo = dict(s.cookies)
    headers['JSESSIONID'] = bo['JSESSIONID']
    r = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.findAll('form', attrs={'class': 'aui-form'}):
        login = item.get('action')
    r1 = s.post(login, data=data, verify=False, headers=headers)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup1.prettify())
```